# ajax post 2 values from html

Tags: javascript, ajax

So i want to post 2 values from my html code to the php code
1 value is - up or down
2 value is - post id

I have posts and when users clicks on up it posts up, post_id

```
<script>
    function vote(val)
    {
        var params = {"vote":val.id};
        $.ajax({
            data:  params,
            url:   'vote.php',
            type:  'post',
            success:  function (response) {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
<a id='up' class='fas fa-angle-up' onclick='vote(this);'></a>
```

vote.php

```
if(!empty($_POST['vote'])) {
    if ($_POST['vote']=='up')
    {
        // Also some how should get second value i think it's done with $_POST['id']
    }
    if ($_POST['vote']=='down')
    {
        // Also some how should get second value i think it's done with $_POST['id']
    }
}
```

Actually i don't really know where i should add post_id since id in a tag is already taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your function with a parameter to up and down vote

```
<script>
    function vote(vote, val)
    {
        var params = {"vote": vote, "id": val.id};
        $.ajax({
            data:  params,
            url:   'vote.php',
            type:  'post',
            success:  function (response) {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
<a id='up' class='fas fa-angle-up' onclick='vote("up",this);'></a>
<a id='down' class='fas fa-angle-down' onclick='vote("down",this);'></a>
```

In your PHP code you can now use `$_POST['id']` to retrieve the id and `$_POST['vote']` to retrieve the down or up vote.